# How to delete all the skin data from a multiple mesh at a time

Tags: armature

I wanted to get rid of Armature modifier and also delete all the vertex groups from multiple meshes at a time, instead of going selecting every object and then removing the modifier and then removing all the vertex groups. (Kile in Maya there is an option to delete history which removes everything from the mesh)

Answer (score 0):

may want to run a little script? open a text editor, create a new blank file and paste this, then run it with your objects selected...

```
import bpy
sel = bpy.context.selected_objects
for ob in sel:
    for vg in ob.vertex_groups:
        ob.vertex_groups.remove(vg)
    for mod in ob.modifiers:
        if mod.type == 'ARMATURE':
            ob.modifiers.remove(mod)
```

Comment: be sure to select only your mesh objects... also to remove all modifiers could link with Ctrl+L to an object with no modifiers at all... and for the vertex groups a single line in a python console would be enough: for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects: ob.vertex_groups.clear()